# How long can my university ask for Erasmus+ money back?

Tags: european-union, currency, advice

I just got an email from my university claiming that they paid too much Erasmus+ money for my study-abroad period and asking me to pay back the amount within the next two weeks.

Since I received my first installment of the grant more than a year ago, I was wondering whether they can still ask me for the money back? After all, there is no way that any person would wait more than a year to see whether they have been paid too much.

Comment: This might be a scam. [Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) are good at spotting these- you might want to ask about it there.

Comment: Also, what country?

Comment: According to [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erasmus_Programme) this is a program run by the EU for EU students studying temporarily in a different EU country. Is that yu situatuion? If so, what country do you reside in, and where did you go to study?

Answer (score 1):

### Read your contract

If they can get overpaid money back will be in there and how they go about doing it will be in there too. Probably.

If it isn’t, then the default rule is that if I overpay you, I’m entitled to change.

There are statutory limits on how long I have to commence legal action to recover a debt - 6-7 years is typical but statutes of limitations vary be jurisdiction.